# How to add class to <body> in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

We can user `Rendered2` in browser version of Angular app but it requires `document.body` reference and it's not available on server rendering.

`platform-browser` has `Title` and `Meta` components but I would like to have more control over `<head>` section, like injecting `<script>` tags, accessing `body` element, etc.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you could always create a variable of type html element, and then document.append that element with the renderer

Comment: @FussinHussin i can't call `document.append` in SSR

Comment: hmmm. you could call it in the lifecycle hook ngAfterViewInit? that way it will wait for the browser to load, which will include the DOM?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, Angular Universal uses [DOMINO](https://github.com/fgnass/domino) library under the hood, which creates `document` in the same way as browser does. The only difference is that you have to inject `DOCUMENT` like this:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document, r: Renderer2) {
        r.addClass(document.body, 'myclass');
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks! One more thing. Domino allows to access `window` object. Is it possible in Angular?

Comment: @untitled, no, Angular server platform doesn't expose `window` in any way