# Angular: I can add class to body, but not apply styles

Tags: angular

First excuse me for my lousy English

I have a problem with rendered HTML. I try to apply a class to the body

I read this post [How to add class to <body> in Angular Universal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346873/how-to-add-class-to-body-in-angular-universal)
I can apply style with `this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'overflow','hidden');`, but I don't know why it's not working with `addclass`

```js
constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, 
private modalService: ModalService, private el: ElementRef, 
private renderer: Renderer2) {
}
open(): void {
   this.element.style.display = 'block';
   this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'ngx-utilitario-modal-open');
   // this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'overflow','hidden');
   console.log('fasd')
 }

 // close modal
 close(): void {
   this.element.style.display = 'none';
   this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'ngx-utilitario-modal-open' )
   // this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'overflow', 'auto' )
 }
```

i see

```html
<body class="ngx-utilitario-modal-open">
```

but style not applying
i try

```html
<div _ngcontent-cvu-c6="" class="ngx-utilitario-modal-open"></div>
```

and this work

Comment: Use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`.
**None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.**

Comment: Show us what CSS you are trying to use, and what the expected behavior should be. There isn't enough information here to correctly answer the question.

Comment: @Spritzig ty, this work

Comment: @renatocohaila If this worked for you I will add as answer and then you can make as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code.

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None.`

**None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.**

Answer (score 0):

Move your style to `styles.scss` or `styles.css` which is applied globally

styles.scss

```
.ngx-utilitario-modal-open {
}
```